# Hibernate Search vs Custom Search

Tags: hibernate, design-patterns, jakarta-ee, hibernate-search

i have a page to search for users with some criterias (id,name,email,department,job)
and right now i am using Hibernate Criteria Queries for my search, and it works very fine. 
i was wondering about the advantages of **hibernate search** with **lucene queries** that will make me use it, instead of using my current custom search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your situation I believe Criteria API is sufficient. Your Criteria API searches can perform good if repeatable are cached and if you perform them over indexed data.

This might be enough if you are having queries of the type:

> Give me all the users of the "FooBar" department.

or

> Give me all the users of the "FooBar" department with job "FooBarIst"

However, if you are operating **over large sets of non indexed data, you might notice performance drop**. For example, if your "name" attribute is not cached, you will notice that a query of the type:

> Give me all the users with the name LIKE "Harr*" 
>   which should give you users by the name

```
Harrold 
Harrison 
Harring 
Harrelson
```

will perform very poorly.

My point is this query will be slow if you haven't indexed the "name" attribute in your database engine. So, if you plan to use such queries, **it is already a good idea to start thinking of a full text search solution**, which Hibernate Search/Lucene/Solr are.

They will give you a lot better performance when searching for email, or some other attrbiute and you are trying to make an auto-complete function, for example.

So, my recommendation to you is the following:
Depending on the scenarios involved, choose whether to use only Criteria API or Criteria API + Hibernate Search/Lucene. Using only Criteria API is fine as long as you know what its limitations are.

Here a common query for the first scenario (where Criteria API is sufficient and Hibernate Search + Lucene is a bit of an overkill):

> All users in the FooBarDepartment

Here is a common query for the second scenario (where Criteria API can do it, but Hibernate Search + Lucene will be a better choice):

> All users that have an email that starts with the letter "f"
>   What about all users that have an email that starts with the letters "fOo" ?

The above query can be done, of course, with plain Criteria API, but if you have millions of users, when making such queries, you will start noticing a significant performance gain in the Hibernate Search/Lucene approach as compared to the plain Criteria approach.

So, in conclusion, whether you use plain Criteria or Criteria + Hibernte Search + Lucene is up to you and depends on the requirements, design and data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as baba suggested as well you get better performance, but above all it provides a huge boost of functionality and better user experience.

The order of returned matches will be (optionally) by *relevance*, and can deal with user typos, autosuggestions and do some smart processing of text (like word similarity) of the searched terms.

You can provide "google like" one field input texts which intelligently match different fields or even entity types; implementing such a feature with Criteria or SQL is a madness of complexity and won't get you as good results.

The best part of integrating your own custom engine based on Lucene is that you can customize pretty much everything for the specific needs of your application, declaratively; for example you define your domain specificy synonyms, and how acronyms are understood by your application.

On top of the generated indexes, it be comes a breeze to perform data mining, document similarity search, etc.. for example you can build tag clouds without needing your users to actually tag stuff by hand: you already have vectors of frequencies for all terms of your database.

An example? the column on the right on this very same website is showing "Related" questions. I don't know if they used Hibernate Search for that, but that's the kind of features it helps to implement.